# How to add block to existing Azure Storage BLOB using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

How does one add a block to an existing block BLOB in Azure Storage?  Ideally, this would be done with PowerShell.  However, I do not see any way of doing so in the [Azure.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/?view=azurermps-6.7.0) PowerShell module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the cmdlets in Azure.Storage module, only support to upload a whole blob, don't support to update part of the blob.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to upload a blob to Azure Blob Storage you should use Set-AzureStorageBlobContent command(Note: there are a param to overwrite an existing blob) take a look on the docs to [Azure.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.7.0) or there are other ways too, like phyton module or AzCopy command, take look to [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not asking how to upload a blob.  I'm asking to upload a new block or page to an already-uploaded block blob or page blob.

Comment: Maybe you could use the param -BlobType and specify the blob as page.